# Unnest multiple columns-list from tibble with tidyr unnes_wider

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

This is my tibble:

```
my_tibble<-tibble(Level = list(c(10,20),c(10,20)),Level2 = list(c(30,40),c(50,20)),Level3 = list(c(330,430),c(530,33)))
```

I want to unnest using unnest_wider all columns: `Level`,`Level2`,`Level3`.

I am doing this: `unnest_wider(my_tibble,Level,Level2,Level3)` and of course is not working.

How can I do this?

Comment: How do you want the column names to be

Comment: It can be: "Level_1","Level_2","Level2_1","Level_2","Level3_1","Level3_3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `unlist2d` with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(collapse)
map_dfc(my_tibble, ~ unlist2d(.x) %>% 
        select(-1)) %>%
     set_names(paste0(rep(names(my_tibble), each = 2), "_", 1:2))
```

-output

```
#    Level_1 Level_2 Level2_1 Level2_2 Level3_1 Level3_2
#1      10      20       30       40      330      430
#2      10      20       50       20      530       33
```

---

Or loop over the names of the data in `map` and apply `unnest_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
map_dfc(names(my_tibble), 
     ~ my_tibble %>% 
          select(.x) %>%
         unnest_wider(.x)) %>%
  set_names(paste0(rep(names(my_tibble), each = 2), "_", 1:2))
```

---

According to documentation from `?unnest_wider`

> .col, col -
> List-column to extract components from.

So, it is just a single column that we can specify where as in `?unnest`, it is `cols`

> cols - Columns to unnest.

Comment: I thought something like `unnest_wider(df, everything())`

Comment: @Laura According to the documentation `col - List-column to extract components from.`  so, it is not more than one column

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps similarly to the answer above using map but with easier naming.

```
map_dfc(colnames(my_tibble), 
        ~ unnest_wider(my_tibble[.x], .x, names_sep = "."))
```